# Understanding of data binding in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am confused with how Xamarin binding works.

OneWay

> Indicates that the binding should only propagate changes from source
>   (usually the View Model) to target (the BindableObject). This is the
>   default mode for most BindableProperty values.

So by default, if the values are set in the view model it will be reflected in the xaml pages.

But in the Xamarin default template, below is the code to insert a new item. Page doesn't have any two way binding mode set in the markup.

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Christianity.Mobile.Views.NewItemPage"
             Title="New Item">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Cancel" Clicked="Cancel_Clicked" />
        <ToolbarItem Text="Save" Clicked="Save_Clicked" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
            <Label Text="Text" FontSize="Medium" />
            <Entry Text="{Binding Item.Text}" d:Text="Item name" FontSize="Small" />
            <Label Text="Description" FontSize="Medium" />
            <Editor Text="{Binding Item.Description}" d:Text="Item description" FontSize="Small" Margin="0" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Here I can see that default values of item are populated when a new page is created and also, edited name and description are available while saving the item.

My question - is two way binding implemented by default without having any binding mode set?

```cs
public partial class NewItemPage : ContentPage
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public NewItemPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Item = new Item
        {
            Text = "Item name",
            Description = "This is an item description."
        };
        BindingContext = this;
    }
    async void Save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send(this, "AddItem", Item);
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
    async void Cancel_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Here is my code to load data asynchronously

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Christianity.Mobile.Views.ItemDetailPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
        <Label Text="Text:" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Item.Title}" d:Text="Item title" FontSize="Small"/>
        <Label Text="Description:" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Item.Description}" d:Text="Item description" FontSize="Small"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
public class ItemDetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ItemListItemDTO SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public ItemDTO Item { get; set; }
    public ICommand LoadItemCommand;

    public ItemDetailViewModel(IPageService pageService, ItemListItemDTO selectedItem)
    {
        SelectedItem = selectedItem;

        LoadItemCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadItem());

    }

    public async Task LoadItem()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            // Both are not working
            Item = await ItemsDataStore.GetItemAsync(SelectedItem.Id);
            //await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
            //{
            //    Item = await ItemsDataStore.GetItemAsync(SelectedItem.Id);
            //});
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to add binding mode in your xaml like `<Entry Text="{Binding Item.Text, Mode=TwoWay}" d:Text="Item name" FontSize="Small" />`

Comment: It is working correctly without setting binding mode, my question is how it is working without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Xamarin.Forms Binding Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode), you can see that most bindable properties have a default binding mode of OneWay but the following properties have a **default binding mode of TwoWay**:

1. Date property of DatePicker
2. **Text property of Editor, Entry, SearchBar, and EntryCell**
3. IsRefreshing property of ListView
4. SelectedItem property of MultiPage
5. SelectedIndex and SelectedItem properties of Picker
6. Value property of Slider and Stepper
7. IsToggled property of Switch
8. On property of SwitchCell
9. Time property of TimePicker

These particular properties are defined as TwoWay for a very good reason:

When data bindings are used with the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) application architecture, the ViewModel class is the data-binding source, and the View, which consists of views such as Slider, are data-binding targets. MVVM bindings resemble the **Reverse Binding** sample more than the bindings in the previous samples. It is very likely that you want each view on the page to be initialized with the value of the corresponding property in the ViewModel, but changes in the view should also affect the ViewModel property.

The properties with default binding modes of TwoWay are those properties most likely to be used in MVVM scenarios.

**Update:**

For example, you get data using Web Api, then loading into ItemDTO Item, please comfirm that you have implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface for ItemDTO class to notify data changed.

```cs
public class ItemDTO:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _Text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _Text; }
        set
        {
            _Text = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    private string _Description;
    public string Description
    {
        get
        { return _Description; }
        set
        {
            _Description = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModelBase is the class that implement **INotifyPropertyChanged**.

```cs
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have another question, I am using same scenario to bind Item properties using MVVM by retrieving it from Web API on OnAppearing event. But the values from api are NOT binded from viewmodel to view. Since it's two way, binding shouldn't it populate?

Comment: @Sunny  Please confirm that you can get data from Web Api to ViewModel firstly, then if your binding is correct, it can display data successfully, it is not related to Two way mode. I don't know if you have problems for your binding, please post your binding code here.

Comment: Thank you for getting back. I have added the relevant code to display the values async. I confirm that the data is successfully retrieved from the webapi but the title and description is not updated in the UI.

Comment: @Sunny Accoridng to your code, I guess that you don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface to notify data changed, please see my update.

Comment: is INotifyPropertyChanged mamdatory for just read only screens.

Comment: @Sunny If you want to notify data changed and update on the UI, you need to implement  INotifyPropertyChanged, you can try it.